# How to return all directories from within FTP site into VB6 Listbox using Inet.OCX?

Tags: vb6, ftp, inet

I have a VB6 project, it connects fine to ftp remote server (i.e : ftp://ftp.microsoft.com), i want to list all the directories names in the ftp server into a ListBox using Inet1.ocx only .
how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Taken from @AhmedEbied's comment to my answer below.*

---

Ok, i got it. We'll use (DIR), the FTP command to retrieve the directories within the FTP server. 
Using (DIR) COMMAND
Inet1.Execute , ("DIR")

```
' CommandButton 
Private Sub Get_Dir_Click() 
  Dim Data as String, Data1 as String 

  ' Get List of all files 
  Do Data1 = Inet1.GetChunk(1024, icString) 
    Data = Data & Data1 
  Loop While Len(Data1) <> 0 

  Text4.Text = Data 
End Sub
```

Of course I had the `UsrName`, `PassWord` and `URL` in place.

Answer (score 1):

You could install an FTP-capable ActiveX component, like this one: [Chilkat FTP](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatftp.asp). Note that there is a free one, called FTP, and a paid version, called FTP2. For your purposes, the free one should be enough.

See [the documentation](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatFtpRef.html) and [the examples page](http://www.example-code.com/vb/ftp.asp) to get started.

Comment: I have no knowledge of `Inet1.ocx`, I'm sorry.

Comment: Ok, i got it.
We'll use (DIR), the FTP command to retrieve the directories within the FTP server.

**General Declaration Section**

    Dim Data,Data1 as String

    Private Sub Get_Dir_Click() 
    'CommandButton
    'Get List of all files
    Do
                Data1 = Inet1.GetChunk(1024, icString)
                Data = Data & Data1
                Loop While Len(Data1) <> 0
                Text4.Text = Data
    End Sub
Of course i had the UsrName,PassWord and URL in place.

Comment: @AhmedEbied You could write that bit of code into an answer of your own and I'd up-vote it. Maybe somebody else has the same problem and arrives here by searching.

Comment: I've tried, but it says (User with reputations less than 100 can not answer their own question) ...
you can copy and paste my comment as an answer and i'm sure others will vote up .

Comment: @AhmedEbied You can propose an edit to my answer, adding the missing context.

Comment: @Tomalek
Thanx a lot for your support.